# Convert vb6 application into windows service

Tags: vb6

I Have an event driven socket reading application that is to be converted into a windows NT Service.

Following is the brief description of my application.

1.Client application (GUI) starts multiple activex exes and assigns sockets to each Activex EXE to read on.

2.Each Activex EXE reads from a socket and triggers events to notify the client application.

3.Client application consumes the events and updates GUI accordingly.

I searched MSDN but unable to find a solution that addresses my current situation.

Please suggest some methodologies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to run "any" exe as a Win32 using srvany.exe, you need to be vary careful how that app handles other processes, windows, shutdown, etc.
Unfortunately, Shelling out to ActiveX EXEs complicates this hugely to the point that it's not practical.

As you say it's a GUI application, how are you expecting that to run as a service? They don't have any UI and normally need to use separate client apps to show any interface.